# Access includes folder in application folder.

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, relative-path

I am using code igniter, and I need to be able to read and/or include some html files, so I created an includes directory in the application folder.

Using CI what is the best way to access this directory?

In my controller I have tried:

```
private $cms_temp_folder = APPPATH . 'includes/';
```

But that gives me the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';
```

Am I approaching this right, or should I be doing it another way?

Comment: Where have your written this, inside any function or in class declaration?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed.

So you have to initialize it in the construct:

```
private $cms_temp_folder;

function __construct() {
    $this->cms_temp_folder = APPPATH . 'includes/';
}
```

It may be even better if you put the path in config file, for example:

```
private $cms_temp_folder;

function __construct() {
    $this->load->config('paths');
    $temp_path = $this->config->item('temp_folder', 'paths');
    $this->cms_temp_folder = ($temp_path == '') ? APPPATH . 'includes/' : APPPATH . $temp_path;
}
```